# Getting error when I try using Sharepoint Online power shell commands

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, powershell-cmdlet

When I try to execute  Powershell command, it gives the error:
Connect-SPOService : The term 'Connect-SPOService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Tried uninstalling and reiinstalling S P Online Management shell. None of the SPO commands are working.

Comment: Ensure the module is correctly installed by running: get-module *sharepoint* -ListAvailable. If this correctly returns the module, try directly importing it into the current session by running: import-module microsoft.online.sharepoint.powershell

Comment: yes, I checked it. Proper version is installed Tried import also. But nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system this came down to a conflicting .dll (different versions) that was found in both the SharePoint PowerShell module folder and the Global Assembly Cache.

I deleted the following file from the GAC:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\tmp\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing\v4.0_16.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll
```

After that everything was running smoothly. Full details on research leading to this is found here:
https://www.easy365manager.com/the-term-connect-sposervice-is-not-recognized/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the cmdlet in the SharePoint Online Management Shell or in the PowerShell? If you are using it in PowerShell, still you need to import the module with

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Besides, ensure you are running the management shell under administrator privilege.

Here is a doc which may be helpful:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: yes. using the cmdlet in SPOnline Management shell. And yes, I had done this import too in Powershell

Answer (score -1):

On mac run the following command:

```
rm -rf Users/<username>/.local/share/powershell/Modules/Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell/16.0.22810.12000/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll
```

PS: replace  with username